# Store site settings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So far I stored the site settings in an array which is inside a file called config.php, however I want to be able to change the settings without needing to edit the file. I thought of moving the settings file to MySQL using something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to know what is considered good practice.

Comment: i didnt get what you need ??

Comment: I believe Wordpress works like this with the `options` and various `meta` tables. I don't personally think it's bad practice per se but if your app/site starts calling it left, right and center I'd figure a way of reducing that

Answer (score 0):

In your way, you will call the configuration by:

```
$result = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings"));
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    $config[$result['name']] = $result['value'];
}
```

But, this is not best practice. Let's see many popular PHP CMS and frameworks, almost people **put configuration in flat files**. Indeed, configuration information rarely change. We don't need save to SQL database (Using SQL when we create, read, update, delete data frequently).